# Intuition for ideal quotient / colon ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm in an introductory commutative algebra class and have come across the notion of the ideal quotient $(I : J) = \{r \in R : rJ \subseteq I\}$ (where $I$ and $J$ are ideals of the commutative ring $R$).

I can manipulate these just fine, and I've seen their usefulness when it comes to working with primary decompositions, but I have no good intuition for what $(I:J)$ "really is". Why is this construction called a "quotient", and when are they used?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950910

Comment: @Watson thanks, that addressed some of my questions, especially the comment pointing out how $((a:b):c)=((a:c):b)=(a:bc)$ translates well to regular division.

Answer (score 6):

In a Dedekind domain, for instance the ring of integers of a number field, then if $I$ and $J$ are ideals with $I\subseteq J$ then $I=J(I:J)$.
In this case $(I:J)$ really is a quotient in the multiplicative sense,
an ideal $X$ solving the equation $XJ=I$.