# Let $R$ be a ring that is Artinian or Noetherian. Show that for some $n>0$, the image of $x$ in $R/0:x^n$ is a non zero divisor on that ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring that is Artinian or Noetherian, and $x\in R$. Show that for some $n>0$, the image of $x$ in $R/0:x^n$ is a non zero divisor on that ring.

How should I approach this question? Should I assume that $R$ is Artinian and then try to prove the second statement and do the same when $R$ is Noetherian, or does it not matter?

Also what does it mean by "the image of $x$ in $R/0:x^n$"?

Comment: I am also curious as to what $R/0:x^n$ means.

Comment: @Arthur Where is the question from? That would help settle the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $0:x^n=\{r\in R:rx^n=0\}$, which is an ideal in $R$ (assuming $R$ is commutative). If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $x\in R$, then the image of $x$ in $R/I$ is the equivalence class containing $x$, usually written $x+I$.

You need to prove that there exists $n$ such that
$$
(a+(0:x^n))(x+(0:x^n))=0+(0:x^n)
$$
implies $a+(0:x^n)=0+(0:x^n)$, that is, $a\in(0:x^n)$: this is the explicit translation of “the image of $x$ in $R/(0:x^n)$ is a nonzero divisor”.

Notice that if $rx^p=0$, then also $rx^q=0$, for every $q>p$. Therefore
$$
(0:x)\subseteq(0:x^2)\subseteq(0:x^3)\subseteq\dotsb
$$
is an ascending chain of ideals. What happens if $R$ is Noetherian?

An Artinian ring is also Noetherian (Hopkins-Levitzki theorem), so examining the Artinian case is not necessary.

Comment: If $R$ is Noetherian then we have a descending chain of ideals. Hence we are done, right?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown What descending chain can you see?

Comment: By the def of Noetherian

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the notation is the same as [Intuition for ideal quotient / colon ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235418/intuition-for-ideal-quotient-colon-ideal), that is

$$(I : J) = \{r \in R: rJ \subset I\}$$

In the given question, we consider

$$(0 : x^n) = \{r \in R: rx^n \subset 0\} = \{r \in R: rx^n = 0\}$$

(I'm not going to go further with solving the question until you've had a chance to think about it while knowing the definition).

In answer to your first question, you may have already proved that any Artinian ring is Noetherian, in which case you can just show that $R$ Noetherian implies the property you're considering. However, if not, you will need to show that $R$ Artinian implies that property as well, which might well require a different proof.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, I just need to state, by a previous problem, any Artinian ring is Noetherian. Since $R$ is Noetherian, then $R/0:x^n$ is a nonzero divisor of the ring. Is that correct?

Comment: No. You need to *show* that if $R$ is Noetherian, then there exists $n$ such that (the image of) $x$ is not a zero divisor of the ring $R/(0 : x^n)$. This is the core of the question (which I deliberately haven't given any help with other than clarifying what $(0 : x^n)$ is).

Comment: You also need to *either* refer to a previous problem / proof from lectures / proof from your textbook which shows that if $R$ is Artinian then $R$ is Noetherian, *or* you need to prove directly that if $R$ is *Artinian* then there exists $n$ such that (the image of) $x$ is not a zero divisor of the ring $R/(0 : x^n)$. Whether you can do the former depends on what you're learning from and what they've included at this stage.

Comment: Having thought a bit more, proving it directly in the case where $R$ is Artinian is only slightly harder than proving it in the case where $R$ is Noetherian, so you probably *shouldn't* use the general result that Artinian implies Noetherian.

Comment: I did previous showed that artinian implies noetherian. So do I need to find an x that satisfies $rx^n=0$?

Comment: No, you need to show that, for every $x$, an $n$ exists such that $x$ is not zero-divisor in $R/(0 : x^n)$, that is, for any $a \in R$ with $a \notin (0 : x^n)$, it is the case that $xa \notin (0 : x^n)$. For the definition of $(0 : x^n)$, see my answer.

Comment: So $x^n=0$ because $x\in(0:x^n)$ and $xa\not\in (0:x^n)$ implies $(xa)^n\neq 0$. Hence $a^n\neq0$