# Is there a name for $I$ in this case with respect to $J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, terminology

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I,J,K$ be its ideals. Let
$I=(0:J)=\{r\in R \mid rJ = 0 \}$. Then $I$ is called the *annihilator* of $J$.

Now let $I=(K:J)=\{r\in R \mid rJ \subseteq K \}$. Is there a name for $I$ in this case *with respect to $J$*? ($I$ is ... of $J$?)

Comment: It is called *ideal quotient*. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235418/intuition-for-ideal-quotient-colon-ideal).

Comment: Thank you. Is $I$  ideal quotient of $J$?

Comment: The other way around, $I$ is the quotient of $K$ by $J$.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde . do you know a book (or paper,...) that uses this notation?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde this question is not duplicate. this different in fact

Comment: See the last answer at the duplicate.

Comment: it does not answer this question